# Identifying Data Type From Binary File

Tags: javascript, file, binary, type-conversion, 8-bit

Using javascript, I want to read data from a file that looks like this:

```
1003 0000 1b0c 0900 0300 1000 0003 0200
0a00 0302 1102 030c 1b00 1a03 0000 0100
1200 030a 090c 1b00 0307 1000 1003 1400
```

What data type is this? Is it a collection of 8-bit unsigned integers?

Comment: Looks like hexadecimal.

Comment: To add to @AlexanderO'Mara's almost certainly correct assertion, this looks like a hex dump into human readable format. Two bytes per four characters i.e. 00-ff (0-255) times by two bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is hexadecimal.  Each one of those 4-digit chunks are the equivalent of 2 bytes or 16 bits.

As far as what it's supposed to represent, that is completely dependent upon how you choose to interpret it.  The data itself does not provide context.  For example, you could choose to interpret that as a very large bitmask, a string, etc.  You need to figure out what it is supposed to represent before you can actually interpret / do anything useful with it.

Comment: Thanks for that, i'm not sure if it's going to be possible to figure out how to interpret this file. It stores a collection of settings from a program. I want to be able to import those settings into my app as it works in a similar way.